# Is there a Java SOAP library capable of handling WS-Security with MTOM?

Tags: java, soap, ws-security, mtom

I'm trying to create a soap client that will need to connect and download files from a service hosted by the government. This service uses WS-Security, and transfers the files as attachments with MTOM.

I've tried a few SOAP libraries, and searched around, but can't find anything suggesting that there is a Java library capable of doing this.

Any ideas?

I've tried:
  CXF with WSS4J,
  AXIS2 with Rampart

Thanks

Comment: I'd expect metro can do it: https://metro.java.net/

Comment: Where you succesful? I'm trying with SAAJ but can't configure security-policies

Comment: We can to the conclusion that nothing existed to do this. We ended up writing our own handler to pull out the encrypted MTOM message, decrypt it, and inject it back into the SOAP body. Was not fun, but it works in the one instance we have to do this in.

Comment: Any way to post pointers on how to approach this handler implementation? I am stuck with this same bummer :)

Comment: You can add an interceptor to your client by doing the following.
`client.getInInterceptors().add(myCustomInterceptor);`

You can create your own custom interceptor by extending AbstractPhaseInterceptor.

`public class MTOMDecryptionInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>`

Once you've done this, its just a matter of pulling the attachment off, decrypting it, and placing it in the main message body.

Answer (score 0):

MTOM uses XOP in order to extract the binary content from the Envelope, and adds a reference to it, in this way soap envelop is much lighter and therefore faster to parse / process.

For that reason inside of the soap envelop you will find estructures as (with just references)

```
<m:photo xmlmime:contentType='image/png'>
    <xop:Include xmlns:xop='http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include' 
                 href='cid:http://example.org/me.png'/>
</m:photo>
```

As the binary content is outside the soap message, WS-Security will not be able to work with it.